Django losing connection with Postrgres creating a tenant
Developing a Django project using django-tenants.
In the moment of new user registration, the tenant has to be created on the host domain with address "project-url.ru/username/..."
Here is view.py with registration
def create_user_tenant(request):

   user = UserClass.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
   schema_name = f'{user.username}_schema'

   try:
    
        with transaction.atomic():
            tenant = Tenant(schema_name=schema_name, user=user)
            tenant.save()
            logger.debug(f'Tenant {tenant} created')
            domain = Domain(domain=HOST_NAME, tenant=tenant, is_primary=True)
            domain.save()
            logger.debug(f'Domain {domain} created for tenant {tenant}')

        logger.info(f'Tenant for {user.username} was created.')

    except IntegrityError as e:
        logger.error(f'Error creating tenant or domain for user {user.username}: {e}')
   
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'Unexpected error creating tenant or domain for user {user.username}: {e}')

def registration(request):

    error_msg = ''

    with transaction.atomic():
        if request.POST:
            logger.debug(f"Registration request")
            form = UserRegistrationForm(data=request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                logger.debug(f"User {user.username} has been registered")
                create_user_tenant(request)
                return redirect('login')

            else:
                error_msg = form.error_messages
                logger.debug(f"Registration form is invalid. Error {error_msg}")

    context = {
        'form': UserRegistrationForm(),
        'error_msg': error_msg,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/registration.html', context)

However, when saving the tenant tenant.save() I get an error:
 The connection 'username_schema' doesn't exist.

At the same time, if I do the same via ./manage.py shell everything works correctly.
DB settings in settings.py:
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        'ENGINE': "django_tenants.postgresql_backend",
        .....

    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
   'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',
    ...

]

Postgres runs in docker. Project run locally on the macos 14.5
Please help me figure out what the problem is with connecting to the database.
I would also be grateful if you could tell me how to organize the availability of a tenant by a domain of the format "project-url.ru/username/..." (but this is secondary)
